Resistance type and value
Resistance type and value please if any body identify


What colour bands there are? Also where was this resistor, in series with  mains input to some device?

As resistor is "accessible", why don't you measure it? It would be a "good" start.

It's a metal oxide reistor.
The colors appear to be blue, green, silver, gold, white.
If they're using the common color codes it's:
Blue = 5
Green = 6
Silver = x 0.01Ω
Gold = 5%
White = Fusible
So you should have a 0.56Ω fusible metal oxide film resistor.
